# SpringBoot RequestMapping method not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning SpringBoot. using Spring JavaPersistenceAPI(JPA) and apache derby as the database. **I am having trouble mapping a URL to a method**.

I have Topics:

```
@Entity
public class Topic {

@Id
private String id;
private String name;
private String description;

public Topic() {

}

public Topic(String id, String name, String description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
} ... getters & setters...
```

---

And I have a Topic controller. It works fine:

```
@RestController
    public class TopicController {

@Autowired
private TopicService topicServ;

@RequestMapping("/topics")
public List<Topic> getAllTopics() {
    return topicServ.getAllTopics();
} 
@RequestMapping("/topics/{topicId}")
public Topic getTopic(@PathVariable String topicId) {
    return topicServ.getTopic(topicId);
}... more methods (they work fine)
```

---

Every topic has courses:

```
@Entity
public class Course {

private String id;
private String name;
private String description;
@ManyToOne
private Topic topic;

public Course() {

}

public Course(String id, String name, String description, String topicId) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.setTopic(new Topic(topicId, "CourseConstructorNAME", "CourseConstructorDESCRIPTION"));
} ... getters & setters ...
```

And I have the **courses controller, where I am finding the problem**:

```
@RestController
public class CourseController {

@Autowired
private CourseService courseServ;

@GetMapping(value = "/topics/{topicId}/courses")
public List<Course> getAllCourses(@PathVariable("topicId") String topicId){
    System.out.println("Hi"); *<-- does not print anything*
    return courseServ.getAllCourses(topicId);
}
```

The problem is that, issuing a GET request to http://localhost:8080/topics/java/courses , returns a 404 error message:

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-11-26T19:30:08.871+0000",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/topics/java/courses"
}
```

I expect a list of courses corresponding to the topic id fetched from the URL. The failure confuses me because the topic controller works fine and it is almost the same.

So, because the sysout I put above doesn't print anything, I must be doing something really dumb; but just in case, here is the code for courseServ:

```
@Service
public class CourseService {

@Autowired
private CourseRepository courseRepo;

public List<Course> getAllCourses(String topicId){
    System.out.println("Calling get all courses from course service");
    List<Course> theList = new ArrayList<Course>();
    courseRepo.findByTopic_Id(topicId).forEach(theList::add);

    System.out.println(theList.toString());

    return theList; 
}
```

and here is courseRepo:

```
public interface CourseRepository extends CrudRepository<Course, String> {

    public List<Course> findByTopic_Id(String topicId);
}
```

Here is the spring console log:

```
2018-11-26 13:29:25.142  INFO 16252 --- [           main] P.ProjectNameWithJpaApplication          : Starting ProjectNameWithJpaApplication on JulioPHX with PID 16252 (C:\SpringToolSuite\workspace\ProjectNameWithJPA\target\classes started by JulioPHX in C:\SpringToolSuite\workspace\ProjectNameWithJPA)
2018-11-26 13:29:25.148  INFO 16252 --- [           main] P.ProjectNameWithJpaApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-11-26 13:29:27.107  INFO 16252 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2018-11-26 13:29:27.238  INFO 16252 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 116ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2018-11-26 13:29:28.254  INFO 16252 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c18d73e6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-11-26 13:29:29.466  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-11-26 13:29:29.501  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-11-26 13:29:29.502  INFO 16252 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
2018-11-26 13:29:29.525  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/amd64;C:\Scripts\;C:\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python37\;C:\Python37\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\MicrosoftVSCode\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;C:\Users\JulioPHX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\JulioPHX\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\SpringToolSuite\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.6.RELEASE;;.]
2018-11-26 13:29:29.773  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-11-26 13:29:29.774  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4461 ms
2018-11-26 13:29:29.852  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-11-26 13:29:29.861  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-26 13:29:29.862  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-26 13:29:29.862  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'formContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-26 13:29:29.862  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-26 13:29:30.698  INFO 16252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-11-26 13:29:30.703  WARN 16252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2018-11-26 13:29:31.587  INFO 16252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Feature not implemented: No details.)
2018-11-26 13:29:31.596  INFO 16252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-11-26 13:29:31.764  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: default
...]
2018-11-26 13:29:31.925  INFO 16252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
2018-11-26 13:29:31.929  INFO 16252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-11-26 13:29:32.247  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2018-11-26 13:29:32.586  INFO 16252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
2018-11-26 13:29:34.603  WARN 16252 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "drop table topic" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table topic" via JDBC Statement

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'SA' does not exist

Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Schema 'SA' does not exist

2018-11-26 13:29:34.718  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@74b00247'
2018-11-26 13:29:34.725  INFO 16252 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-11-26 13:29:36.108  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2018-11-26 13:29:36.251  WARN 16252 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-11-26 13:29:36.757  INFO 16252 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-11-26 13:29:36.763  INFO 16252 --- [           main] P.ProjectNameWithJpaApplication          : Started ProjectNameWithJpaApplication in 12.543 seconds (JVM running for 13.617)
2018-11-26 13:29:42.083  INFO 16252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-11-26 13:29:42.084  INFO 16252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-11-26 13:29:42.100  INFO 16252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 16 ms
2018-11-26 13:29:42.298  INFO 16252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

And the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>PackageNameWithJPA</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectNameWithJPA</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>ProjectNameWithJPA</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

**Project structure:**

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: try to rename your package do lowercase. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Another thing, post your Project.....Application.class

Comment: How are you configuring your context?

Comment: You seem to have different root package names for topic and course: *PackageNameWithJPA*.topic and *ProjectNameWithJPA*.course. Is this intentional? If you are scanning from PackageNameWithJPA, then your course controller won't be included.

Comment: @Jason Yes, It is intentional but I am just beginning to learn this framework so if this is not the way to do it, I will change it . I will then include topic and course controllers in the same package _PackageNameWithJPA_ ... Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I have same problem .It is because your Properties default is set to:
"spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop"

change it 
in application.properties file.if this not over there add this

> "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update"

line in your application.properties file.It work fine.

Answer (score 5):

Even I have encountered the same error while using Apache Derby. This is because of the default properties of spring which is `-spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`.

**Solution:** Create an `application.properties` file in `src/main/resources` folder and change the property to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` and run the app again, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason being the second controller in package "ProjectNameWithJPA.course" is giving 404 error because spring is not able to scan controller in "ProjectNameWithJPA.course".

By default, Spring-Boot scans the controller under the same package hierarchy like it can be "PackageNameWithJPA.course"

Read this for more understanding spring docs [https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will read that article and update the project structure accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can always define a custom component scan in a spring boot project. By default @SpringBootApplication annotation handles the component scanning for the application. However, let’s say one of the components is defined in another package then you can define in your configuration class like :

@ComponentScan({"com.springboot.basics.springbootPA1","com.springboot.springbootPA2"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class testApplication{